# How do I make ale highlight using a virtual environment

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin, neovim, vim-ale

I just started configuring Vim as an IDE, and the first file I launched into was one that happened to use a Virtual Environment.

In my .vimrc, I added [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) as my lint engine, and [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) as my autocomplete (intellisense) engine. So I entered, and saw there were errors. I exited vim, and then sourced my virtual environment and entered again, and there were still errors. For some reason, though, they were all at the imports.

I've tried:

- Sourcing my venv before entering vim
- Putting `let g:ale_virtualenv_dir_names = ['env']` in my .vimrc
- Using the [vim-virtualenv](https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv) plugin

I setup ale's linters and fixers as the following

```
 " ALE vars
 let g:ale_disable_lsp = 1
 let g:ale_linters = {
        \   'python': ['flake8'],
        \   'javascript': ['eslint'],
        \}
 let g:ale_fixers = {
 \   'python': ['black'],
 \}
 let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
 let g:ale_sign_warning = '-!'
 let g:ale_virtualenv_dir_names = ['env']
```

but it still throws the errors

How do I make it warn using my Virtual Environment?

Comment: Please add the errors you are getting.

Comment: Yes, adding the error and errorcodes you are getting will help.

Comment: For one of the imports: `E0401: Unable to import 'flask_nav' (import-error)`
You can repeat this for all the pip modules in my venv

Comment: I posted an answer, but it didn't work after checking again

Comment: Edit your answer and put in your full error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it. **EDIT: I DID NOT FIX IT**

In my .vimrc file, I just needed to indent this code block.

```
let g:ale_fixers = {
     \   'python': ['black'],
     \}
```

It must have made vim and ale confused and threw errors, especially since I put that before my `g:virtualenv_dir_names` variable.

## **UPDATE**

#### That was not what was causing the problem

It was all to do with my virtual environments, for some reason. If anyone can explain this to me, I'll be thankful.

I needed to `rm -dr` my virtual environment I had before, and then remake and reinstall it.

Hope this helps some of you!

Comment: **The update is correct.** The piece about indentation was incorrect, although it might help.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you are using `Neovim` (or that this solution will also work for `Vim`) but YMMV.

==> Run the command `:checkhealth provider` in neovim. You want to look for the part about python 3:

```
## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/home/albaraa/Documents/venv_global/bin/python3"
  - INFO: Executable: /home/albaraa/Documents/venv_global/bin/python3
  - INFO: Python version: 3.8.5
  - INFO: pynvim version: 0.4.2
  - OK: Latest pynvim is installed.
```

============================================================================

If it doesn't say `OK`, just follow the prompts given:

- If it can't find your python version, then in your init.vim file put the location of your virtualenv:

```
let g:python3_host_prog = '/home/albaraa/Documents/venv_global/bin/python3'
```

- If it finds it and you still get an error, just follow the prompts. You will need to run this command INSIDE your virtual environment:

```
pip install neovim pynvim
```

============================================================================

If it says `OK` but it is still not working:

- Make sure that you are running neovim in the python virtual environment. I have an alias for Neovim setup like this so that I can type in `nvimp` and have it do it automatically:

```
alias nvimp="source ~/Documents/venv_global/bin/activate && nvim"
```

- Check whether you can access your python virtual environment inside neovim. I think some older versions had a problem with this:

```
" This should show your virtual environment
:which python

" This should show your virtual environment in the path
:echo $PATH

" This should show your virtual environment is in the path of the neovim command shell (has to be the same as above)
:!echo $PATH
```

Comment: I'm not using neovim, but this could be good for some that are.